# How to determine which processes have unevictable memory?

Tags: linux, memory-usage

looking at /proc/meminfo, I can see the total amount of unevictable and mlocked memory on the system:

```
Unevictable:    23265536 kB
Mlocked:        23265536 kB
```

How do I determine which processes are responsible for this unevictable memory?

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/[pid]/status` shows how much is locked by mlock(), 
and the command `ipcs` shows how much is locked via shared memory.